# urge + preposition

Tags: verbs, prepositions

I just read in the [NY Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/02/09/world/middleeast/trump-arabs-palestinians-israel.html)

> "We **urge** them **from** taking a unilateral position"

Is it possible to urge someone from doing something?

Comment: I do not think you can "urge from" but you can "dissuade from"

Comment: It sounds very awkward to me; I would expect "urge to" and "urge not to".

Answer (score 2):

The [NY Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/02/09/world/middleeast/trump-arabs-palestinians-israel.html) misquoted another publication, [The Jerusalem Post](http://www.jpost.com/Israel-News/Politics-And-Diplomacy/Trump-warns-Israel-Stop-announcing-new-settlements-480446).

The NY Times article actually states,

> Within hours of Mr. Trump’s meeting with King Abdullah, the administration leaked a statement to The Jerusalem Post saying, *"We **urge all parties from taking** unilateral actions that could undermine our ability to make progress, including settlement announcements"*

The correct quote, provided in the Jerusalem Post:

> "With that in mind, we **urge all parties to refrain from taking** unilateral actions that could undermine our ability to make progress, including settlement announcements."

The actual quote is using the phrase *"urge all parties **to refrain**"*, correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This [definition of urge](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/urge) does not list the prepositions that may or may not be used with it.

However, it does list these examples with prepositions.

- to urge dogs **on** with shouts.
- urged **by** necessity.
- to urge a person **to** greater caution.

I have heard *urge to* most often, but have not heard "urge from." When I read the NYT *urge them from taking a unilateral position* in question, it sounded a little unusual.